# Is there a way to automatically add a code in a newly created worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want see if there is a way to track changes in a newly created tab only. Below are two sets of code that I've come up with in my research. For reference, "Overview" is where I put all the inputs that the newly created tab will have and "Variance Template" is the template I copy for the newly created tab. Now, when I create a new tab using the macro, I also need the tracking code to be copied within that new tab. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Create a new tab code:

```
Sub AddNewTab()

'Assign Overview tab to be read as "ws"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Overview")
 
'Assign newly created tab as "newWs" and rename it to cell D6 in Overview tab
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Set newWs = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
newWs.Name = ws.Range("D6").Value

'Copy data from other, already created, comparison tab into new tab
Worksheets("Variance Template").Range("A1:A59").EntireRow.Copy
newWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Worksheets("Variance Template").Range("A1:BJ59").Copy
newWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

'Copy comparison name/month/year, last closed month/year, and service type
ws.Range("D6").Copy
newWs.Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ws.Range("Q8").Copy
newWs.Range("L2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ws.Range("Q12").Copy
newWs.Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Hide gridlines in newly created tab
newWs.Activate
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

'First disables any freezed panes, then freezes panes to row 9 & column 7
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
Cells(9, 7).Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Disables "ignore errors" notices
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False

'Change zoom to 80%
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80

'Change tab color to green
ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

End Sub
```

Tracking Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:BJ200")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With newWs
            .Range("F3").Value = "Last Updated: " & Environ("username") & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss_ AM/PM")
        End With
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I need this code to copy over every time I create a new tab using the first set of code. I'm relatively new to VBA so let me know if you need any other type of information.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a template worksheet with that code in the worksheet module, and create your new sheet as a copy of that.  In the event code use `Me` to refer to the sheet itself (ie. not `newWs`)

Comment: I tried putting in the tracker code in the Variance Template worksheet, but when I run the code to create a new worksheet, it doesn't have the tracker code in it. Is this what you mean? I also tried this again after changing `newWs` to `Me`. Moreover, when I tried running the tracker code with just `Me`, on a sample page, the code doesn't come up. Is there another way the tracker code can identify the current worksheet?

Comment: Is this all happening in the same workbook?

Comment: Yes. So I need the tracker code to be in the newly created worksheets within the same workbook. The tracker needs to track any changes made to `range("A1:BJ200")` and put `.Range("F3").Value = "Last Updated: " & Environ("username") & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss_ AM/PM")` in the same worksheet. Let me know if I need to clear up anything else. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub AddNewTab()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Overview")
     
    ' Variance Template is a hidden sheet (first tab position)
    '    zoom, freeze panes etc are already set up on this sheet
    wb.Worksheets("Variance Template").Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    
    Set newWs = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count) 'get the copy
    With newWs
        .Visible = True
        .Name = ws.Range("D6").Value
        .Tab.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Range("F2").Value = ws.Range("D6").Value
        .Range("L2").Value = ws.Range("Q8").Value
        .Range("P2").Value = ws.Range("Q12").Value
        .Activate
    End With
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!!! Thank you so much!!